# Meeting Optimiser in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, optimization

I have been tasked with scheduling meetings on a bulk scale. My dataframe consists of individuals and the time slots they are able to do. As an example:

```
Person  TimeSlot
1       1
1       2
1       3
2       2
3       1
3       2
4       2
```

The ideal output based off the data would be a single time slot for each person based off their preferences above. Lets also say that, in the case of Person 2 and Person 4 who only have TimeSlot 2 available, Person 2 gets preference as they submitted their response earlier (Person Numbers are assigned in order of time submission):

```
Person  TimeSlot
1       3
2       2
3       1
4       N/A
```

Only I have far more people and time slots. There are more time slots than people. Any help on this would be much appreciated. I initially tried looping through each individual, assigning the first slot they picked. But I ran into an issue where Person 1 for example was assigned TimeSlot 1, Person 2 assigned TimeSlot 2, but Person 3 could not be assigned a time as both their preferences had been taken.

Answer (score 0):

**Enters: [maximal pairing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm)**

Fortunately for you, the problem is rather well explored and many libraries do already implement the algorithm. For example [networkx](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable//reference/algorithms/matching.html). Simply construct the graph and use the function as per documentation.
In your case you are trying to find maximal pairing person ~ time_slot in a bipartite graph with edges leading from a person to every timeslot he marked.

Alternatively, if your data is within a reasonable size, brute force is an option.

Or if you want to get fancy then network flows can also solve your problem. The network is Source - people - time_slots - sink and the maximal flow finds the pairings.